# Www and non www sites

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a domain say http://www.testexample.com. When I login to http://www.testexample.com and come back to http://testexample.com in browser; the logged in user information is not displayed.
I know that the both of the above are treated differently and hence it is not retaining the session for http://www.testexample.com while accessing http://testexample.com.

Please let me know if cakephp has a way to do a match on the TLD. So whenever I type http://testexample.com it should take session for http://www.testexample.com

I am using the following code to redirect from one URL to the other

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off   
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ps6309 [NC]   
RewriteRule ps6309.domain.co.in [L,R=301]
```

this is on my local test machine. This works sometimes and sometimes doesn't.
Also I have added the rewritelog directive to my httpd.conf file. 
But the log file is not getting updated. 
Please let me know if anyone has any pointers to this.

Comment: better fit to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions voting to close

Comment: Voting up.. to nullify who voted this question down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use .htaccess to redirect all http://domain.com -> http://www.domain.com

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Comment: u posted first thats y deleted mine :-)

Comment: I think this is a better solution, because then the user will only use one domain, and the experience will be less confusing (e.g. the visited links would change if he visited two domains). Also, it's better caching, since we will have only one copy of each resource.

Comment: extactly - serving both urls makes no sense. use 'www' over ''.

Comment: I am using CakePHP & how would I format your user to accommodate for app/webroot like so-> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app/webroot/$1 [R=permanent,L]. I want to add 'www.' before app/webroot. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Set the domain for the cookie as testexample.com, then it can be shared across sub domains as well as not worrying about www.

Comment: I am Using Cakephp Auth component for session and the user information is coming from the same. Would it be achieved with cookies then?

Comment: Even though you are using sessions a cookie is still created so that the user can be matched to the session file (or table) on the server. I don't know Cake, never used it but check this out, might point you in the right direction. http://kodegeek.wordpress.com/tag/cakephp/

Answer (score 3):

If you have many projects and don't want to hard code your domain name on .htaccess again and over again, try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

this will redirect non-www to www. While you're using cakephp, then put it on your .htaccess which is located at `/webroot`

Comment: +1 this is much better way of adding `www` to your domain but even better is: `RewriteRule . http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 0):

Try `ini_set('session.cookie_domain', $domain);` (documented [as ini_set session.cookie_domain](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain) and [`session_set_cookie_params()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)), where $domain is your domain name prefixed by a `.`. So, using the domain example.com (per [rfc 2606](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606.txt)), you'd use:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com');
```

Please note that this is not a CakePHP specific solution - looking at [the code for CakeSession](http://api13.cakephp.org/view_source/cake-session/#line-467), `session.cookie_domain` is never set, meaning that it falls to it's default value. Stuffing that line in your `app/config/bootstrap.php` or `app/config/core.php` should do it for you.