# When I type "www.gstbox.com" it doesn't work but it works fine without "www"

Tags: dns, hosting, names

At first my website was hosted on [000webhost.com](http://000webhost.com) but then I had some problems with them so I switched for [networksolutions.com](http://networksolutions.com)(paid).

But after a while I realized that when I entered on [www.gstbox.com](http://www.gstbox.com) it showed me that the page is not found but if I typed in [gstbox.com](http://www.gstbox.com) it works just fine what could possibly be the problem??
Please help

Answer (score 1):

there have been a lot of these questions answered here please use the search box in the top right corner of the page, most can be answered with a rewrite rule. here is the answer to your question. [Www and non www sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042309/www-and-non-www-sites)

Answer (score 0):

---

Or possibly there might be a firewall and its not allowing the www.gstbox.com to pass,or else maybe your web service is not configured to respond to the same page on www

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that www.gstbox.com is a subdomain of gstbox.com which is simply not listed in  gstbox.com's DNS server. You should have some kind of control panel for your domain (if you don't, contact an operator of your service provider) where you are able to change the DNS settings. You should add a www subdomain and configure it to point to the proper IP address (most likely the same as the one gstbox.com points to).

I hope it helps,
Regards